# Synonym or short phrase for 'entablature'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests

I am not sure if this word has multiple meanings, but I am using it in an architectural context.  Classical orders have distinctive columns with distinctive capitals.  However, when I say each style also has a distinctive *entablature*, I am guessing many readers won't know what what the word entablature means (I didn't). So next to the word 'entablature', I would like to put in parentheses a synonym or *very short* phrase that defines the word 'entablature'.

Essentially, my question boils down to:  **What is a synonym or very-short phrase for the word 'entablature'?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a simple explanation of entablature](http://architecture.about.com/od/buildingparts/g/Entablature.htm):

> In Classical architecture, the entablature is **the upper portion of a building, above the columns and below the roof**.

Entablature usually consists of a main beam called the [architrave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architrave), a wide central part, often decorated, called the [frieze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze), and a top molding called the [cornice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornice#Classical_architecture).

[image: http://architecture.about.com/od/buildingparts/g/Entablature.htm]

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really a synonym, but you can give a short list of example types rather than an alternate word (lintel, architrave, frieze, cornice, etc.) in the running text to give the reader a hint, and perhaps add a more complete definition in a footnote.

Comment: This is a seriously good idea

Answer (score 2):

How about "upper façade"? That's not precise, but it conveys the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who doesn't know what an *entablature* is, which I didn't before tonight, I think using *cornice*, *frieze*, and *architrave* is not going to help, although it would work for people who are familiar with architecture.  Being largely ignorant of architecture myself, I'd describe it personally as an *upper border* or *roof facing*.